# how can i remove the current UV image texture off a mesh?

Tags: materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I am currently using the blender render engine and i have a mesh with an UV image texture, but i don't want it anymore. How can i remove it?

[image]

Comment: You can do that [by hand](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file) (just don't press **Shift** if you don't like to completely remove image from file) or [using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31362/unlink-image-from-the-image-editor-using-python).

Comment: Do you want to remove the image from the .blend? Or just from the object? If you just want to remove it from the object, how is it associated with the object? (does it appear in the render?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go into the texture panel with the object selected, and find the texture with the image you want to remove, then click the X on the top right and the texture/image will be removed from the object
[image: the "x" in the textures panel]